# logrotate-like functionality for database tables/file system files

Tags: java, database, filesystems, logrotate

tl;dr summary: **Are there standard solutions for limiting the length of database tables and number of file system files based on number, disk space or time?**

---

I have a Java web service that allows users to run operations that are internally handled as jobs. In order to access results of previously run jobs or asynchronous jobs the user gets a handle in the form of a job ID. I save all this information in a few database tables of a relational database (currently Apache Derby) because it's much more convenient than inventing a new file format (and also probably much more reliable and performant). The actual job results are saved as XML files in the file system.

Job execution may be very frequently (1/s and up) so the tables/directories might get quite large after some time. What I need is a method that allows pruning the job history of the oldest entries based on

- job count (a maximum of *n* jobs and their results should be saved)
- table/directory size (the tables should take at most *n* GB of space on the hard drive)
- when the job was run (keep only jobs that completed at most *n* days ago)

I'm not decided which solution to take yet so the more flexibility the better. I fear when I implement this myself the solution might be quite error prone and it would take some time to get the system robust. The software I'm developing should be able to run for a very long time without any interruption (Ok, whose doesn't...).

Comment: If the jobs are going to be very variable, perhaps it would be a good idea to implement two (or all three) of the options you outline and assign the housekeeping method per job dependent on the job profile?

Comment: @Ed Harper: There are no job profiles. All jobs contribute to the global job history that needs pruning based on _some_ strategy (three examples of which I outlined in the question). As I said, I'm a bit hesitant to implement this myself because I think it's going to get very complex to cover all corner cases. Of course, if there are no standard solutions, I'll do it. But I don't think I'm the first on the planet with a system like this.